# A problem on the rank of a new type of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ of order $m\times n$ with entries from a field of characteristic zero. Define $A^\theta$ as the transpose of the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing each of its non-zero elements by their inverse and leave zeros as such. Show that $Rank(AA^\theta)=Rank(A^\theta A)=min\{Rank(A),Rank(A^\theta)\}$.

Comment: Please observe that the OP defines a special kind of "transpose" which is not identical to the usual one.

Comment: Actually is says (usual) transpose of a matrix obtained by modifying $A$, so indeed it in general differs from the transpose $A^\top$ of $A$, though it does have the same shape as $A^\top$.

Comment: Yes. My comment was given with regard to a first one citing a reference to an answer only involving the "ordinary" transpose of $A$. Obviously the comment in question has now been deleted. Just wanted to highlight that there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Take as field $k=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $A=(1~~1)$. Then $\def\rk{\operatorname{Rank}}\rk(AA^\theta)=0\neq1=\rk(A^\theta A)$.

Comment: In your example isn't it that $A^{\theta}A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix having all entries equal to one thus with rank zero?

Comment: @BerndH All entries equal but nonzero means the rank is $1$; rank $0$ applies only to a zero matrix (of any size).

Comment: Yes, of course. Rank zero is indeed only the special case with all entries zero.